# How can I get the 10 first lines of all my compressed files?

Tags: bash, unix, zsh, bz2

I have a bunch of `M` files, from which I want to extract the first `N` lines (from **each**). My files are compressed in BZ2. Otherwise, doing `head -10 *` would be enough.

Ex: Assume I want to extract the 2 first lines from all my files (A.txt, B.txt, C.txt underneath).

A.txt:

```
1A
2A
3A
4A
```

B.txt:

```
1B
```

C.txt:

```
1C
2C
```

The expected result should be something like that (ie containing these lines, not forced to be in order):

```
1A
2A
1B
1C
2C
```

I tried the following:

- `bzcat * | head -10` gives me the **first 10 lines** of the whole decompressed bunch of files, ie not enough output. I would have only `1A 2A` here.
- `bzcat | head -10 *` gives me the first 10 lines of each **compressed** file, ie it's impossible to read.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for i in *; do bzcat "$i" | head -n10; done
```

or `find`:

```
find -type f -exec bash -c 'bzcat $1 | head -n10' _ {} \;
```

Comment: Would you know why it doesn't work with pipes? Would you have another solution using pipes without braces?

Comment: you need to process the files one by one, so the pipe is used to serialize the 2 actions you need to perform on each file

Comment: but is there not a way to serialize the 2 actions directly on the bunch of files?

Comment: yes, you could and that's what you indicated in your question. In this case you decompress all files and get only the first 10 lines of the 1st file, but that's not what you want. The `for ` loop is the easiest `bash` statement that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) :

```
find . -name "*" | xargs -I {} sh -c "bzcat {} | head -n10"
```

*xargs -I replace-str :*

> Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments
>                 with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do
>                 not terminate input items; instead the separator is the
>                 newline character.